# Customizing OpenCart - How should it be done?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm developing an OpenCart shop using OC 2.1 and I'm struggling to understand what is the best solution for creating custom changes on controller level.

Here's a simplified example to show you what I'm wondering about:

I'd like to modify my header. The graphic design I'm implementing uses different writing for *My account* link depending on if the user is already logged in or not. This is of course a very simple thing to change, so here are my ideas:

I could just edit my new template's `header.tpl` file to use:

```
<?php echo $logged ? $text_account_signed : $text_account; ?>
```

That requires a change in a language file and that file is outside of the template folder. I'll leave the language issue out for this example to make it less complicated.

But to create a solution that is more MVC I should make that change in the `catalog/controller/header.php` file, shouldn't I? Unfortunately that file is outside of the template folder so in case of an update, the change will be lost or would require fixing by hand.

I could however create an extension with an `extension.ocmod.xml` file that would make a change in the controller `header.php` file and it would be safer (not sure if 100% sage though) for future updates. But the amount of extensions and/or the complexity of creating them would greatly impact my project time, I suppose. And that makes me tempted to just edit the source code of OpenCart and make my future self worry about it later. But I care about this guy and I'm sure he'd hate me for that at some point.

So, my real question is: Is there a way of creating OpenCart modifications on controller level that would not break future updates?

Comment: Please read this, hope, help for you- (1) http://docs.opencart.com/developer/module/  (2) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-beginner-to-advanced-in-opencart-understanding-mvc--cms-21627

Comment: I understand creating my own modules. I am wondering about how to edit the modules that are in OpenCart by default.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding modifying existing `Controller, Models, Languages` yes you either need to use [vQmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki) or [OCMOD](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System) and for `template` yes you can create your own template according to need. there is no other option.

If you are using vQmod or OCMOD then you don't have to worry about updates because there is less chances of issue (issue may occur only in major updates).

For vQmod there are other easy tools like [vQgen](http://uksb.github.io/vqgen/) and [vQmanager](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2969) available

For Opencart Overall [general info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru)